# How to Get Listbox item in textbox with mouse click?

Tags: c#

I have a listbox named `listbox1` in which emails are collected. I want the `listbox1` item in `textbox1` by selecting that item.

That i can do by:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

All emails have the same format: `a@gmail.com`, `b@gmail.com`.
I want the selected item in textbox without the `@gmail.com` part.

How can i achieve this?

The items collected in the listbox are:

- ab@gmail.com
- bc@gmail.com
- gh@gmail.com

I want to take just `ab` or `bc` or `gh` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [String.IndexOf method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) to find the position of the `@` symbol and then [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the username from the email:

```
var emails = new List<String>() 
{ 
    "abc@gmail.com", 
    "xyz123@gmail.com", 
    "a@gmail.com" 
};
emails.ForEach(email => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf("@")));
});
```

The output for the example-input is:

```
abc
xyz123
a
```

Applied to your text box case, a solution can look like this:

```
var email = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
textBox1.Text =  = email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf("@"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('@')[0];
}
```

Comment: its saying invalid argument

Comment: error 1:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]' 
Error 2:The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: the quotation marks around the @ symbol should be single, not double.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by finding the index of the `'@'` sign and then using `SubString()` to only the email address.

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedEmail = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();    
    textBox4.Text = selectedEmail.SubString(0, selectedEmail.IndexOf("@") - 1);
}
```

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'SubString' and no extension method 'SubString' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: It's `Substring`, not `SubString` (only 1 capital letter).

Comment: this one works but it skips one letter at the last///suppose its brian it get only bria